# What's the meaning of "Skip the rock stars"?

Tags: meaning

In the [Rework](http://37signals.com/rework/) book written by Jason Fred there is a chapter named "Skip the rock stars". 
Can somebody tell me what does it mean?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on asking answerable questions. At a minimum, we need context (what is the book about? What is the chapter about?) and an overview of what research you have attempted thus far.

Answer (score 1):

[Skip the rock stars](http://blogs.wsj.com/accelerators/2014/03/21/weekend-read-skip-the-rock-stars-hire-the-band/), that is,  avoid recruiting rock stars:

> - Skip the Rock Stars, Hire the Band:
> - Quick – name your favorite one-man band. You know, someone who masterfully juggles a guitar, harmonica and foot drum at the same time. Who’s your favorite?
> - If you’re stumped, there’s a reason. Precious few people produce anything truly memorable or inspiring when they try to do it all. Usually, they just burn themselves out. It’s necessary for every business to hire talented, competent people who have a vision and are willing to work hard to achieve it. But it is not sufficient. The real secret to success is to hire a rock band – maybe even a whole orchestra – **rather than simply focusing on recruiting big-name rock stars.**

(from The  Wall Street Journal)

Comment: I was about to add an answer, but I don't want to also be called *dude*. @Hamed Read the essay, then you'll understand the title.